# Wondering what "get by" means in this context

Tags: vocabulary

> He tries to **get by** with the least amount of **work possible**.

Could you tell me what this sentence means?

Comment: *Possible* modifies the entire NP *the least amount of work*, not just *work*. You may also say *the least possible work* or *the least possible work* or *as little work as possible*.

Answer (score 3):

It means that he tries to survive the situation by working as little as possible.

The situation would depend on the context. It could be his work, his studying, etc. (It's likely about his work, but students also have to do their work too.)

As a bonus, here is what **[get by](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-by)** means,

> to have just enough of something such as money or knowledge so that you can do what you need to do

Instead of saying "survive the situation", you could use words such as "manage", "to cope with", "make ends meet", etc., too. You can find them in your dictionaries and thesauruses.

Comment: Thank you so much, but would you give an example as to that situation? or would you give me areal situation, so that I can find what my original sentence means?

Comment: Suppose that the task was a group assignment, and his group had to compete with another group. So his situation was to win the other group, but he might be too lazy to do the work. He would prefer not to do anything, and let other members in the group do all the work. When they asked him to do his work, he would do it as little as possible, enough for not being blame once the team lost the competition. That's how he got by.

Comment: Would you possibly give me another easier example?

Comment: @nima_persian, understand it like this: *He tries to [get by] with [[the least amount of work] possible].* It could be rephrased as: *He tries to get by with the least possible amount of work.*

Comment: And, could you give me an exact synonym for GET BY in such situation?

Comment: @nima_persian Synonyms are never exact. I've also already given a few synonyms of "get by" in my answer. As I said, you can find them in your dictionaries and thesauruses.